# Using os.walk in Python

Tags: python, os.walk, file-not-found

I am trying to replace a character in multiple files in multiple subdirectories (over 700 files in 50 or so subfolders).  This files works if I remove the path and place the file in the specific folder; however, when I try and use the os.walk function to go through all subdirectories, I get the following error:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

It points to the last line of my code.  Here is the code in its entirety:

```
import os

path = "C:\Drawings"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk( path ): # parse through file list in the current directory 
    for filename in files: #os.listdir( path ):
        if filename.find("~"):# > 0: # if a space is found
            newfilename = filename.replace("~","_") # convert spaces to _'s
            os.rename(filename,newfilename) # rename the file
```

Comment: Your `filename` is relative. You need to use `os.path.join(root, filename)`. The same holds for `newfilename`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been mentioned, you need to give the rename function full paths for it to work correctly:

```
import os

path = r"C:\Drawings"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk( path ): # parse through file list in the current directory 
    for filename in files:
        if "~" in filename:
            source_filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
            target_filename = os.path.join(root, filename.replace("~","_")) # convert spaces to _'s
            os.rename(source_filename, target_filename) # rename the file
```

It is also best to add an `r` before your path string to stop Python trying to escape what comes after the backslash.

Comment: Thank you for this.  That taught me quite a bit and solved my problem.

Comment: I'm glad it solved your problem. You can also click on the tick next to the answer to accept the solution. This will also get you a badge.