# Incorrect file reading when using os.walk in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk, file-not-found

I am crawling through folders using the `os.walk()` method. In one of the folders, there is a large number of files, around 100,000 of them. The files look like: `p_123_456.zip`. But they are read as `p123456.zip`. Indeed, when I open windows explorer to browse the folder, for the first several seconds the files look like `p123456.zip`, but then change their appearance to `p_123_456.zip`. This is a strange scenario.

Now, I can't use `time.sleep()` because all folders and and files are being read into python variables in the looping line. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(srcFolder):
        os.chdir(root)
        for file in files:
            shutil.copy(file, storeFolder)
```

In the last line, I get a file not found exception, saying that the file `p123456.zip` does not exist. Has anyone run into this mysterious issue? Anyway to bypass this? What is the cause of this? Thank you.

Comment: What's incorrect about this?  Are you getting an exception when you try to open the files?  If so what is the exception and traceback?  Or are you just assuming that Python is going to pull the wrong names? Is it possible that the folder has both `p_123_456.zip` and `p123456.zip` in it and it just takes windows explorer some time to sort the filenames for display?

Comment: I want to move the files to other folders. So when the name is read it is without '_'. But when I call the moving operation it says such a file does not exist.

Comment: When you move the files are you giving the full path of the source file? `source_full_path = os.path.join(root, fname)`

Comment: Please, add the line(s) where you actually try to open/rename the files.

Comment: Thank you, @StevenRumbalski, please see the edited question.

Comment: Thank you, @jsbueno, please see the edited question.

Comment: What happens if you change that to `shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, file), storeFolder)` ?

Comment: This looks like a problem with not understanding that `os.walk` returns `list`s of unqualified names. Already covered in [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32380631/364696).

Comment: Oh, wait, `os.chdir` is being used. That might fix part of it, while breaking other things. Don't use `os.chdir`, because that will break any relative paths you might be using (or that any library might be using). Just use `os.path.join` to qualify the names and leave the working directory alone.

Comment: Okay, I just tested it.  I was able to get `shutil.copy` to work by changing `os.chdir` to my source directory and then was able to copy an unqualified name.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Yeah, I reopened on that basis. That said, if `srcFolder` or `storeFolder` is a relative path, `os.chdir` will break things; `os.walk` relies on a consistent working directory in that case, per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk): "Note: If you pass a relative pathname, don’t change the current working directory between resumptions of `walk()`. `walk()` never changes the current directory, and assumes that its caller doesn’t either." This code violates that assumption.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: You should connect all these dots into an answer.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Not sure it's the cause though; would need to know what `srcFolder`/`storeFolder` are defined as. Using `os.chdir` for this purpose is bad form, but it's more likely to cause iteration to stop prematurely (the first `chdir` makes all the entries in `dirs` invalid, and it just stops; might differ by OS or specific Python version I'll admit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't seem to be concatenating the actual folder name with the filenames. Try changing your code to:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(srcFolder):
    for file in files:
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, file), storeFolder)
```

`os.chdir` should be avoided like the plague. For one thing - if the changes suceeeds, it won't be the directory from which you are running your os.walk anymore - and then, a second `chdir` on another folder will fail (either stop your porgram or change you to an unexpected folder).

Just add the folder name as prefixes, and don't try using chdir.

Moreover, as for the comment from ShadowRanger above, `os.walk` officially breaks if you `chdir` inside its iteration - https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk - that is likely the root of the problem you had.